# PHP's PDO loop returning all excluding first row

Tags: php, symfony1, pdo

Got problem with `PDOStatement->fetch` under *symfony* (v1.4.6) as while fetching records from statement first row is always excluded.

Code bellow:

```
<?php var_dump($stats->rowCount()); ?>
<?php var_dump(count($stats->fetchAll())); ?>
```

Produces:

```
int 14
int 13
```

And code bellow:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php var_dump($stats->rowCount()); ?>
<?php while ($v = $stats->fetch()): ?>
    <?php var_dump(++$i); ?>
```

Produces:

```
int 14
int 1
int 2
int 3
int 4
int 5
int 6
int 7
int 8
int 9
int 10
int 11
int 12
int 13
```

Any ideas why row is excluded?

Comment: Aside from @Pascal's valid comments about it not being something you should rely on, my best guess is simply you already did a `fetch` somewhere (`fetchAll` gets the _remainder_ of the resultset, which might not be the _whole_ resultset).

Comment: Well this is obvious but code was checked lots of times and iam 100% sure there is no fetch before that and that is really annoying

Comment: Rowcount is not a random number. There might be an error in Symfony, I don't know. Can you cobble together a example also showing the creation of the `PDOStatement`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem **SOLVED** and it wasn't PDO related but Symfony related problem (one of the OutputDecorators i think but don't know sure yet)

PDOStatement was valid and when looping through it with `->fetch` inside controller everything was fine (14 records retrieved). After moving the same code to view first record was always excluded from results (and i think its related with that output decorators are using Iterator and ArrayAccess).

Quick workaround for this issue is NOT using `while loop` but make usage of implemented `Iterator` and `ArrayAccess` so final code that works as expected (returns all rows) is using `foreach`

```
<?php foreach ($stats as $v): ?>
    <?php //do stuff with record ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

insted of `while` + `->fetch()` loop

```
<?php while ($v = $stats->fetch()): ?>
    <?php //1st record is missing here somehow ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the documentation of [**`PDOStatement->rowCount`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) :

> If the last SQL statement executed by
> the associated PDOStatement was a
> SELECT statement, some databases may
> return the number of rows returned by
> that statement. 
> However, **this
> behaviour** is not guaranteed for all
> databases and **should not be relied
> on** for portable applications.

and the note on Example #2 :

> For most databases,
> `PDOStatement::rowCount()` does not
> return the number of rows affected by
> a `SELECT` statement.  
> Instead,
> use `PDO::query()` to issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement with the same
> predicates as your intended `SELECT`
> statement, then use
> `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` to
> retrieve the number of rows that will
> be returned. 
> Your application can
> then perform the correct action.

So, not really an answer to the *why* of your question, but I would say you should not use `rowCount()` for a `select` query ;-)

See also the notes on that documentation page ; for example, [this one][2], which says *(quoting)* :

> It appears that rowCount behavior is
> different on Mysql 5.0 vs 5.1.

And, with a query as simple as `"SELECT 1"` :

> Mysql 5.0.45, PHP 5.2.5 returned 1
>
> Mysql 5.1.30, PHP 5.1.6 returned 0

Comment: Ok but i know that the row is missing. When i run query in MySQL CLI i got 14 rows returned `mysql> ... 14 rows in set (0.00 sec)`, and the same SQL through PDO returns me only 13 rows with fetch/fetchAll method

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, one way to solve this is to `fetchAll()` and iterate over the array. In my case this caused a second problem: iterating over 10.000 records gave a memory error.

After some digging in to Symfony I saw there is a posibility to set variables directly instead (using `$this->setVar` in your action methods). `setVar` has 3 parameters: the variable name in the view, the actual data, and if the data is safe (than it will be escaped). When the data isn't safe / escaped, all records are in the mysql statement. Allowing you to loop over row with fetch.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem (first row not showing up while iterating over rows), but it was my own fault.

In my template I had:

```
<?php if(!$statement_iter->fetch()): ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach($statement_iter as $row): ?>
...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When the PDOStatement had any rows the foreach loop would always exclude the first row.

Obviously (I realize now), the if-statement is calling fetch(), which will move the cursor forward by one. So, the if-statement was eating up the first row! Derp.